Sort by Date Day Names
I have this code that successfully displays the number of orders according to the day-name of the week. However, I wanted to display the days name sorted accordingly.
I have this code below:
SELECT 
    DATENAME(dw, orderDate) AS day_of_week, 
    COUNT(orderID) AS total_orders
FROM 
    Orders
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(dw, orderDate)

Here's the output: But I wanted the Days(name) sorted from Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.. and so on.

Any idea? Thank you in advance.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

And please provide sample data in consumable form e.g. create table ... insert into table... to allow us to test.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Thank you for all the comments and reminders.

I think you are looking for DATEPART with the WEEKDAY parameter e.g.
with cte as (
  select DateOfTest
  from (
    values
    ('19 Oct 2024'),
    ('18 Oct 2024'),
    ('17 Oct 2024'),
    ('16 Oct 2024'),
    ('15 Oct 2024'),
    ('14 Oct 2024'),
    ('13 Oct 2024')
  ) x (DateOfTest)
)
select *, datename(weekday, DateOfTest)
from cte
order by datepart(weekday, DateOfTest);

Returns:



DateOfTest





13 Oct 2024
Sunday


14 Oct 2024
Monday


15 Oct 2024
Tuesday


16 Oct 2024
Wednesday


17 Oct 2024
Thursday


18 Oct 2024
Friday


19 Oct 2024
Saturday



DBFiddle
So your query becomes
SELECT 
    DATENAME(weekday, orderDate) AS day_of_week, 
    COUNT(orderID) AS total_orders
FROM 
    Orders
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(weekday, orderDate), 
    DATEPART(weekday, orderDate)
ORDER BY
    DATEPART(weekday, orderdate);

Note 1: Depending on your server settings and requirements you may need to specify which day of the week is first e.g. SET DATEFIRST 1;.
Note 2: I highly recommend using the full parameter name e.g. WEEKDAY instead of the abbreviation DW - its makes it much clearer for anyone reading your query in future.

Thank you! This works!  Added the last line on my query (datepart).

Depending on your datefirst settings you could try
SET DATEFIRST 1; -- first setting datefirst
SELECT 
    DATENAME(weekday, orderDate) AS day_of_weeks, 
    DATEPART(weekday, orderDate) AS day_number, 
    COUNT(orderID) AS total_orders
FROM 
    Orders
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(weekday, orderDate), 
    DATEPART(weekday, orderDate)
ORDER BY 
    day_number ASC;


on your server you first check your datefirst setting by calling @@DATEFIRST

@Anis Please don't misuse comments to add further information to your answer, rather edit the answer.
